# Plot legend doesn't appear like it should be

Tags: plotting, legending

I constructed a plot with extra legends generated using dashed function but customarily defined legend doesn't look like plot:

```
Y1 = Sin[x]; Y2 = Cos[x]; Y3 = Sin[2*x] + Sin[5*x]; Y4 = 
 Sin[7*x]; Y5 = Sin[9*x];
 Plot[{Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5}, {x, 0, 15}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, All}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style["Y1", Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica, 22], 
 Style["Y2", Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica, 22], 
 Style["Y3", Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica, 22], 
 Style["Y4", Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica, 22], 
 Style["Y5", Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica, 22]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, AxesStyle -> Dashed, 
 FrameLabel -> {"r [\[Mu]m]", 
 "T [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]\), \(0\)]\
 \)C]"}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontWeight -> Plain, 
 FontFamily -> Helvetica}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Thick], 
 Directive[Dashed, Red, Thick], 
 Directive[Dashing[{0.025, 0.01, 0.025, 0.01}], Purple, Thick], 
 Directive[Black, 
 Dashing[{0.025, 0.005, 0.025, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
 0.005}], Thick], 
 Directive[Blue, Dashing[{0.025, 0.01, 0.005, 0.01}], Thick]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]
Note legend 3,4,5 are not like the plot or defining parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the lengths of the `LegendMarkers` just need to be increased.

```
Y1 = Sin[x]; Y2 = Cos[x]; Y3 = Sin[2*x] + Sin[5*x]; Y4 = Sin[7*x]; Y5 = Sin[9*x];
Plot[{Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5}, {x, 0, 15}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, All}, Axes -> {True, True},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontWeight -> Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica},
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[(Style[#, 22] &) /@ {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5"},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 75],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, AxesStyle -> Dashed,
 FrameLabel -> {"r [μm]", "T \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\([\), \(o\)]\)C]"},
 PlotStyle -> {{Orange, Thick},
   {Dashed, Red, Thick},
   {Dashing[{0.025, 0.01, 0.025, 0.01}], Purple, Thick},
   {Black, Dashing[{0.025, 0.005, 0.025, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005}], Thick},
   {Blue, Dashing[{0.025, 0.01, 0.005, 0.01}], Thick}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Plot with larger legend marker lengths]

***Update***

Given your comment below about being good for a research article and if you really had to stick to a single figure, I would just use solid lines of varying thickness and color contrasts.  Here's an example (and certainly not the best choice):

```
Plot[{Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5}, {x, 0, 15}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, All}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontWeight -> Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica}, 
 PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 22] &) /@ {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5"}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, AxesStyle -> Dashed, 
 FrameLabel -> {"r [\[Mu]m]", "T \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\([\), \(o\)]\)C]"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Green, Thickness[0.01]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.01]}, 
   {Purple, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Cyan, Thick}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Figure with solid lines]

Comment: That cool JimB. I have a little more concern is this plot is good for a research article or u think I can improve it more?.

Comment: It might very well be because I don't know the subject area but I find the figure to be essentially unintelligible.  Especially the curves for Y4 and Y5.  I don't think an improvement in resolution would help.  Would it make sense to have (at least) two figures?  Or maybe having Y4 and Y5 having very different patterns (like solid and dotted) as Y1, Y2, and Y3 are much more distinguishable by their shapes.

Comment: Thanks JimB for the suggestion. The think is I want to use different plot-marker apart from just color and widths but having no idea to how include different type of marker like *,# ... in PlotStyle function. It seem I can only include solid, Dashed and Dotted which I already used.

Answer (score 4):

You may be over specifying the appearance of the plot and legend.

- For [`PlotLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegend.html) within the plot consider making use of [`Automatic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) for the line style and the [`LabelStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelStyle.html) option for the labels.
- For [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) consider making use of the [`PlotTheme`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html).

There was mention of needing styling for publication.  I recommend the `"Monochrome"` `PlotTheme` as each style will be distinguished when printing monochrome.  This with the above suggestions gives

```
Plot[{Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5}, {x, 0, 15},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, StringTemplate["Y``"] /@ Range@5,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1},
 AxesStyle -> Dashed,
 FrameLabel -> {"r [\[Mu]m]", 
   "T [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]\), \(0\)] \)C]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Colour can be added to this theme by specifying a colour-only scheme after `"Monochrome"` in `PlotTheme`.

```
Plot[{Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5}, {x, 0, 15},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, StringTemplate["Y``"] /@ Range@5,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1},
 AxesStyle -> Dashed,
 FrameLabel -> {"r [\[Mu]m]", 
   "T [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]\), \(0\)] \)C]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
 PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome", "BoldColor"},
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.